# Is it possible to give related items in a collection the same ID?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm building a simple MERN application, where users submit reviews about cafes. I'd like users to be able to click on a cafe name, the be directed to a page where all the reviews for that particular cafe are shown. 
To do this, I need to filter through the reviews and return only the reviews pertaining to the specific cafe. So how do I give review documents from the same cafe a common ID? Or am I approaching this the wrong way? I did manage to fitler reviews based on Cafe name, but I feel that it's bad practice to do so.

**Review post route and model**

```
app.post('/api/add-review',(req,res) => {
    const review = new Review(req.body)
    review.save()
    .then(() => {
        console.log('review successfully posted')
        res.status(200)
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
})
```

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const reviewSchema = new Schema({
    userName:String,
    stars:String,
    title:String,
    photo:String,
    blurb:String,
    cafe:String
}, {timestamps:true})

const Review = mongoose.model('reviews', reviewSchema)

module.exports = Review
```

**Cafe GET route and model**

```
app.get('/api/all-cafes', (req,res) => {
    Cafe.find()
    .then((result) => {
        res.send(result)
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
})
```

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const cafeSchema = new Schema({
    cafeName:String,
    photoURL:String,
}, {timestamps:true})

const Cafe = mongoose.model('cafes', cafeSchema)

module.exports = Cafe
```

Here's the component that displays the list of cafes - where I want users to be able to click on a cafe, and be directed to the cafe's reviews.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import Cafe from './Cafe'

const CafeList = () => {
    const [cafes, setCafe] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('/api/all-cafes')
        .then(cafe => {
            setCafe(cafe.data)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
    },[])

    return(
            <div className = 'cafe-container-container'>
                <h2>Cafes</h2>
                <Cafe cafes = {cafes}/>
            </div>

    )
}

export default CafeList
```

```
import React from 'react'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'

const Cafe = (props) => {
    const {cafes} = props
    return(
        <div>
            {
                cafes.map(cafe =>{
                    const {cafeName,photoURL} = cafe
                    
                    return (
                    <Link to = {`/cafe-reviews/${cafeName}`} style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }} >
                        <div className = 'cafe-container'>
                            <h2>{cafeName}</h2>
                            <img src = {photoURL}></img>
                        </div>
                    </Link>
                    )
                })
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default Cafe
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you approach is good. but you should add cafe property as the following

````
const reviewSchema = new Schema({
    userName:String,
    stars:String,
    title:String,
    photo:String,
    blurb:String,
    cafe:{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'Cafe'
    }
}, {timestamps:true});
```
and add this in you cafeSchema
```
cafeSchema.virtual('reviews', {
    ref: 'Review',
    localField: '_id',
    foreignField: 'cafe'
});
```
Using in this way has several benefits like if you are accessing any review you do not need to go back and fetch info about its cafe there will be whole cafe object not only id..there is som other things you can explore about it
````

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I tried your code but only got an empty array back, though.

Comment: Where you got empty array? I mean what you are trying to access?